# how to identify cells containing less than current date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to know how to get the date (listed in column A) that are less than the current date.

In column B, what formula should I use?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njAeH.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean referencing the cells with `Sheet1:A1`?  And I don't understand the second part of your question at all.

Comment: That means nothing to me

Comment: Can oyu update your question with this information?  That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: can you help me

Comment: Not really, but your question is now a lot clearer for someone that might know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I udnerstood:
You want to get dates in ColumnA that are less than ColumnB

Date_A is the range of dates in column B

```
=IF(Date_A<$B$2;Date_A;"")
```

[image]

Comment: Column B is blank................... What  i want to happen is from the list of date in column A. I like to appear in column B those date that are less than the current date (01 DECEMBER 2017)

Comment: Then you can use: =IF(Date_A<Today();Date_A;"")

Answer (score 0):

I cant think of an way to use excel function only to achieve that. If the order of entries are not important, below is a workaround. You can make dates after today blank in column B

```
=IF(A2<TODAY(),A2, "")
```

and then sort it from oldest to newest. Think will put blank cells (entries with date after today in cloumn A at the bottom).

If you are fine with VBA, you can use a loop to do that, which would do exactly what you want.